# Pandas how to use boolean indexing to update column from second dataframe column?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, merge, boolean

I have two dataframes, each of which has two columns:  unique_id, price. 
df1 has a subset of all unique_id's in df2.

Now I need to add a third column to df1 that has the price for that unique_id element in df2. i.e. the columns will be:
unique_id, price, price2.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Faster is use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'unique_id':[1,2,3,1,2,3],
                   'price':[4,5,6,7,8,9]})

print (df1)

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'unique_id':[1,2,3],
                    'price':[46,55,44]})

print (df2)

df1['price2'] = df1['unique_id'].map(df2.set_index('unique_id')['price'])
print (df1)
   price  unique_id  price2
0      4          1      46
1      5          2      55
2      6          3      44
3      7          1      46
4      8          2      55
5      9          3      44
```

---

```
np.random.seed(123)
N = 1000000
L = np.random.randint(1000,size=N)
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'unique_id': np.random.choice(L, N),
                   'price':np.random.choice(L, N)})
print (df1)

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'unique_id': np.arange(N),
                   'price':np.random.choice(L, N)})

print (df2)

In [60]: %timeit df1['price2'] = df1['unique_id'].map(df2.set_index('unique_id')['price'])
1 loop, best of 3: 168 ms per loop

In [61]: %timeit df1.merge(df2, on='unique_id', suffixes=['', '2'], how='left')
1 loop, best of 3: 373 ms per loop

In [62]: %timeit df1.join(df2.set_index('unique_id'), on='unique_id', rsuffix='2')
1 loop, best of 3: 252 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 3):

Consider the dataframes `df1` and `df2`

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
        'unique_id': [1, 2, 3],
        'price': [11, 12, 13],
    })

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'unique_id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    'price': [9, 10, 11, 12, 13],
})
```

***`merge`***

```
df1.merge(df2, on='unique_id', suffixes=['', '2'], how='left')

   price  unique_id  price2
0     11          1       9
1     12          2      10
2     13          3      11
```

***`join`***

```
df1.join(df2.set_index('unique_id'), on='unique_id', rsuffix='2')

   price  unique_id  price2
0     11          1       9
1     12          2      10
2     13          3      11
```

***Experimental: FAST***
*Using `numpy.searchsorted`*

```
def pir1(d1, d2):
    u1 = d1.unique_id.values
    u2 = d2.unique_id.values
    p2 = d2.price.values
    a = u2.argsort()
    u = np.empty_like(a)
    u[a] = np.arange(a.size)
    return d1.assign(price2=p2[a][u2[a].searchsorted(u1)])

pir1(df1, df2)

   price  unique_id  price2
0     11          1       9
1     12          2      10
2     13          3      11
```

---

***Timing***
**`pir1` fastest method**
*small data*

```
%timeit pir1(df1, df2)
1000 loops, best of 3: 279 µs per loop

%timeit df1.assign(price2=df1['unique_id'].map(df2.set_index('unique_id')['price']))
1000 loops, best of 3: 892 µs per loop

%timeit df1.merge(df2, on='unique_id', suffixes=['', '2'], how='left')
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.18 ms per loop

%timeit df1.join(df2.set_index('unique_id'), on='unique_id', rsuffix='2')
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.02 ms per loop
```

*large data*
*Using @jezrael's test data*

```
np.random.seed(123)
N = 1000000
L = np.random.randint(1000,size=N)
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'unique_id': np.random.choice(L, N),
                   'price':np.random.choice(L, N)})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'unique_id': np.arange(N),
                   'price':np.random.choice(L, N)})


%timeit pir1(df1, df2)
10 loops, best of 3: 104 ms per loop

%timeit df1.assign(price2=df1['unique_id'].map(df2.set_index('unique_id')['price']))
10 loops, best of 3: 138 ms per loop

%timeit df1.merge(df2, on='unique_id', suffixes=['', '2'], how='left')
1 loop, best of 3: 243 ms per loop

%timeit df1.join(df2.set_index('unique_id'), on='unique_id', rsuffix='2')
10 loops, best of 3: 168 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 3):

another solution:

```
df1['price_df2'] = df1['unique_id'].map(df2.set_index('unique_id')['price'])
```

again borrowing @piRSquared's sample DFs ;-)

```
In [42]: df1
Out[42]:
   price  unique_id
0     11          1
1     12          2
2     13          3

In [43]: df2
Out[43]:
   price  unique_id
0      9          1
1     10          2
2     11          3
3     12          4
4     13          5

In [44]: df1['price_df2'] = df1['unique_id'].map(df2.set_index('unique_id')['price'])

In [45]: df1
Out[45]:
   price  unique_id  price_df2
0     11          1          9
1     12          2         10
2     13          3         11
```